# why my Beautiful Soup not getting query strings of links?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get href of anchor tag by BeautifulSoup, but it doesn't retrieve query strings!
this is the html snippet:

```
<td class="titleColumn">
  143.
  <a href="/title/tt1302006/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962- 
  327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=0GYQY7SGFV9AK9CV3019&pf_rd_s=center- 
  1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_143"
  title="Martin Scorsese (dir.), Robert De Niro, Al Pacino" >The Irishman</a>
    <span class="secondaryInfo">(2019)</span>
</td>
```

and this is the link returned by soup:

https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?sort=us,desc&mode=simple&page=1/title/tt1302006/

and this is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
add="https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?sort=us,desc&mode=simple&page=1"
r = requests.get(add)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
i=1;
for movie in soup.find_all("td",{"class":"titleColumn"}):
    print (add+movie.find('a')['href'])
```

links in soup doesn't has query strings too

Comment: Are you sure the query strings are in the HTML, and not added later by JavaScript?

Comment: that was not the issue but thanks for your attention

Comment: First of all, use `r.content` instead of `r.text` if the result is HTML or XML (amongst others). Second, what does _it doesn’t retrieve query strings_ mean, exactly? It returns only a single string, which also happens to be wrong? What does _links in soup doesn’t has query strings too_ mean?

Comment: It's something with the request, I've tried with `cURL`, changing user agent, and using urllib, the raw HTML doesn't show the query variables like he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes web server responds differently if you don't define a user-agent. Click following link to read more about user agents.

https://www.howtogeek.com/114937/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-user-agent/

Here's how you can define user agent header in your code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
add="https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?sort=us,desc&mode=simple&page=1"
r = requests.get(add, headers = {'User-Agent': "user-agent"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
i=1;
for movie in soup.find_all("td",{"class":"titleColumn"}):
    print (add+movie.find('a')['href'])
```

Comment: Try to replace "user-agent" string with another i.e. "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"

Comment: This is the right explanation, but you have to use a user agent that a real browser sends. Copy the value of `navigator.userAgent` from a browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
user-agent = 'valid user agent'  #enter a valid user agent here
add="https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?sort=us,desc&mode=simple&page=1"
r = requests.get(add, headers = {'User-Agent': user-agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
i=1;
for movie in soup.find_all("td",{"class":"titleColumn"}):
    print (add+movie.find('a')['href'])
```

notice i used **r.content** not **r.text**. i also find that sometimes using a valid user agent can be really helpful in these situations